# Trying to get property of non-object error problem

Tags: laravel

I'm new in Laravel. Can u guys help me what's the problem with this?

**Trying to get property 'id_rotation' of non-object**

This is my Controller :

```
public function edit_panel_date(Request $request)
{
    $input_date     = $request->date;

    $nik    = Sentinel::getUser()->nik;

    $data   = AccelerateMentee::select(
        'accelerate_mentee.*',
        'accelerate_rotation.start_date',
        'accelerate_rotation.id as id_rotation'
    )
    ->leftJoin('accelerate_rotation', 'accelerate_rotation.id_mentee', '=', 'accelerate_mentee.id')
    ->where([
        ['accelerate_mentee.nik', '=', $nik],
        ['accelerate_rotation.status', '<>', 'approved']
    ])
    ->first();

    $update = AccelerateRotation::where('id', '=', $data->id_rotation)
    ->update([
        'panel_time_start'  => $input_date
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Hope u guys can help me resolve this problem, thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `->first();` doesn't have any result. Check if `$data` is not empty before update

Comment: Did you make sure there's a data that related to the models? Have you tried `dd()` the `$data` variable?

Comment: How to use dd() function? Where should I place the dd?

Comment: your $data variable getting null. if you change ->first to ->firstOrFail you will see it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

have you return `$data` and have you get `$data->id_rotation` ?
if `$data` empty, you cant get `$data->id_rotation`

Comment: I check it with dd($data), the result is null